# PHP/MySQL randomly failed to parse the correct datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm getting an issue with datetime when inserting to the MySQL. I cannot tell if it was caused by PHP, Apache server or MySQL server which parsed the datetime to "1969-12-31 18:00:00". It happens vey randomly. While everyone has no problem insert the PHP date to MySQL, one or two users failed to get a proper datetime value from the same code. Those users are not consistent.

In PHP:

```
$thetime    = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

So, I guess there is nothing wrong with that line, unless the server returns the wrong datetime.

I'm using MyISAM. I also suspect MyISAM caused the problem if 2 clients inserting 2 records at the same time.

It could be Apache server is not doing its job properly. It might return the wrong datetime.

My question is that how I point out what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the variables as recommended in here

```
mysql> show variables like 'date%format';
+-----------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name   | Value             |
+-----------------+-------------------+
| date_format     | %Y-%m-%d          |
| datetime_format | %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s |
+-----------------+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

source: https://serverfault.com/questions/313400/datetime-format-changed-between-mysql-5-0-and-5-1

Comment: Hi, that was not the point. I insert datetime string to mysql with the correct format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s`. The Unix epoch randomly parsed  although all users use the same code: `$thetime    = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`